# How to represent transpose of a block matrix that doesn't transpose each block?

Tags: matrices

Can $$\left[\begin{matrix}
A \\
B
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
be written as $[A,B]^T$? If not, how can I write it without spanning multiple lines?

Does $[A,B]^T$ mean $$\left[\begin{matrix}
A^T \\
B^T
\end{matrix} \right]?
$$

Answer (score 1):

$[A^T,B^T]^T$ is what you want. Also, $[A,B]$ only makes sense if you know that $A$ and $B$ share the same number of rows.